# How to get value of text tag using selenium from below DOM structure need to fetch "147"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

This tag is under element with id:

```
{
    <text class="donutChartText" text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="16" fill="#78a22f"

    style="fill: rgb(120, 162, 47); font-family: openssanslight; font-size: 55px; 

    opacity: 1;">147</text>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using getText() method of selenium.

For Eg: suppose Web Driver instance is 'driver' so corresponding Java code will be

```
String s = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("text[class='donutChartText']")).getText();
```